# how to verify if html5 is supported by the browser

Tags: html

When you make a site in HTML5, is there any tool or whatsoever to verify if your HTML5 code is supported by all existing browsers Internet Explorer, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, Android ..

Comment: You test it with each targeted browser...

Comment: Nothing can replace good old fashioned testing. There are automated tools you can use like Selenium to help with that, but you still need to know what to test.

Comment: Well you have to test each browser(versions) you want to support. There are services like Browserstack that make this a little easier, but is not free

Comment: Yes was looking into some automated tool, where you type the site, press verify, and as a result a list will appear telling you whether the site is supported by the browser or not. Does it exist. Will try Selenium. As I can see with canIuse you manually have to verify if all tags in the site is supported or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing-
As long as your HTML5 is valid, browsers render most of the times correctly.
Check it - https://validator.w3.org/

Secondly-
Check if there are any issues in your console. Make your JS error free and CSS non-overlapping.

Lastly-
There are some frameworks that you can use like - Selenium or PhantomJS or ZombieJS etc., through which you can write automation test cases and check if it works in different environments.

PS: Forever the best way to test is checking in each environment manually. There is nothing that can match it. Automated test cases are good for validating data and other things. But, to check out the rendering capabilities, I feel manual testing is the best.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, just what I was looking for. Apparently people might think it is a stupid question, but I am new to this. Thanks

Comment: Glad to know I was of help. Adding to it, try to follow "Best Practices" when it comes to HTML5 and CSS3 development, and follow "Design Patterns" and "Principles" when you code JS. Following them pretty much neatly will usually not cause any problems :) Happy coding...